# jquery datepicker change display to inline or contents

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the datepicker's display from block to contents or anything else.  If you use the console it displays as block I am trying to switch to inline, contents etc.

```
  $( ".dp2" ).datepicker({
 numberOfMonths: 3,
 showButtonPanel: true,beforeShow: function()
    {
        $(".ui-datepicker").css('display','contents')
    }
});
```

[Change Jquery Display](http://jsfiddle.net/99m260fo/)

Comment: do you want to change the display on button click or just have it from the start?

Comment: You code not following minimum standard at all. Why you datepicker initializing with span instead input?

Comment: Not using input because I want them to show on page load and onclick I will write response to another input.

Comment: I would like to change the display from the start or on click.  I have other datepickers on the page so I don't want to change all pickers only the `$( ".dp2" )` picker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inspect the datepicker after it renders and see what classes it has. The below css code can do what you are looking for. its important to use `!important` to override the default `block` display

```
.ui-datepicker {
    display: contents !important
}
```

If you want to use jQuery to add the css with `!important` while preserving the current css you can do

```
$(".ui-datepicker").css("cssText", function() {
  return this.style.cssText + "; display: contents !important;";
});
```